# webroot entire path in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have some trouble with an Yii2 application. 
I need to put into a variabile the complete webroot path of my application, in my case www.mysite.it/language/catalogue/. When I call the function to retrieve this information, I get www.mysite.it/application/web where application/web is the root of my project.

I have tried this function:

```
$home = Yii::$app->request->getAbsoluteUrl();
```

It is any way to do what I want?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about the baseUrl `Yii::$app->request->getBaseUrl()`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `yii\helpers\Url` features

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-url.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html

and eg_ for home  `Url::home()`

```
 $absoluteHomeUrl = Url::home(true);
```

or for `Url:to()`

```
 $url = Url::toRoute(['language/catalogue/']);
```

the use of the UrlHelpers prevent your code from different url result related 
 to your urlManager config  (with or without pretty url)